# Local variables in view body

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a SwiftUI `View`'s `body`, I store intensive work in a local variable, which I use in its subviews (Like through a context menu).

I do this to avoid doing the expensive work multiple times per view refresh, if I use the variable multiple times in the view body.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        let num = viewModel.expensiveWork
        
        Text("Number: \(num)")
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Press me \(num)") {
                    viewModel.doWork()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num = 0
    
    var expensiveWork: Int { num * 20 }
    
    func doWork() {
        num = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
    }
}
```

It works fine right now, but I was just wondering if this is good practice, and if it **could cause any desynchronization issues**.

I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @loremipsum Your right, but I think it helps if you use that variable multiple times

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You created the MRE, but I threw that in in case you hadn't read it. This question will get flagged as it is asking for an opinion. What you have done is acceptable, but I suspect most would prefer the variables to be declared outside the `body`.  In the original SwiftUI this wasn't allowed.

Comment: @Yrb But if it was declared as a computed property, then the expensive work would have to be done multiple times every single time the view body refreshes, whereas with a local it only computes one time per view body refresh

Comment: @Yrb Also thank you for the question advice! I will use that on later questions

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The whole struct will be re-evaluated, so that won't change the amount of evaluations.

Comment: @Yrb But I can't access any `self` properties if I do it in a regular property (not computed).

Comment: @Yrb What I mean is that if I use `num` multiple times in the view body, then using a  local will save some evaulations

Comment: No, it won't. Structs are completely disposable. The body is not just reevaluated. The entire struct is.

Comment: @Yrb I know that, but what I mean is that if I use the computed resource multiple times inside the View body, wouldn't it be better to store that computed resource as a local?

Answer (score 1):

Because `expensiveWork` is a computed property and you are calling it in the view `body`, you are still doing the work every time the view `body` gets recomputed.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Number: \(viewModel.expensiveWork)")
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Press me \(viewModel.expensiveWork)") {
                    viewModel.doWork()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num = 0
    @Published var expensiveWork = 0

    func doWork() {
        num = Int.random(in: 0..<100)

        Task {
            // Intensive work here while it is asynchronous
            let result = num * 20

            await MainActor.run {
                expensiveWork = result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Can it cause desynchronisation issues?

Yes - `num` and `expensiveWork` may be set at different times. To avoid this, change `doWork()` to the below code:

```
func doWork() {
    let temp = Int.random(in: 0..<100)

    Task {
        // Intensive work here while it is asynchronous
        let result = temp * 20

        await MainActor.run {
            num = temp
            expensiveWork = result
        }
    }
}
```

This comes at the trade-off that now `num` won't update until the expensive work is done.

Comment: "Because expensiveWork is a computed property and you are calling it in the view body, you are still doing the work every time the view body gets recomputed." - What I mean is that if I use `expensiveWork` multiple times inside the view's body, then a local variable would reduce the number of evaulations. Thank you for the comprehensive answer though!

Comment: @489320758 Correct. But that one evaluation is still costly (for this imaginary scenario). In my example above, this work is done on a separate thread only when it's needed (`doWork` was called). Otherwise, each time the view `body` is recomputed that work will unnecessarily be done again and again even if `num` doesn't change. The `body` cannot be calculated until `expensiveWork` is calculated in your case, which can lead to longer view creation/updating times.

Comment: I think I named `expensiveWork` badly, because it isn't like any type of networking / expensive math operation, its just a simple `.filter` operation. I think I'm prematurely optimizing here

Comment: @489320758 Same principle applies because it's still work that may take some time and doesn't have a predictable finish time. You could have `filter` run each time the body is recomputed, and depending on the size of the collection, this might make negligible performance impact anyway. However, you are still saving performance by only performing the calculations as necessary, i.e. when `doWork` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Do the expensive work in the model and reference it. Structs are disposable; everything gets reinitialized all of the time and you can't control that.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Number: \(viewModel.expensiveWork)")
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Press me \(viewModel.expensiveWork)") {
                    viewModel.doWork()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num = 0
    
    var expensiveWork: Int = 0
    
    func doWork() {
        num = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
        expensiveWork = num * 20
    }
}
```